# Deserialization and Async/Await

Tags: c#, windows-8, async-ctp, async-await

In my app (Windows 8 Metro) I store some objects in the local Folder in a serialized format. Here's the method to read then back (see below).

If I call this method with Task.Run, I can get the object:

```
var entity= Task.Run<Entity>(() => GetASync<Entity>(file)).Result;
```

but if I use the await keyword, it's not working - on the line A (ReadObject) in the method the thread stops and exit with no error or exception:

```
var entity= await GetASync<Entity>(file);
```

Maybe I don't use await / async as it's recommended?

The method

```
private async Task<T> GetASync<T>(IStorageFile file) where T : class
{
    try
    {    
        if (file != null)
        {
            IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            IInputStream inputStream = readStream.GetInputStreamAt(0);                   
            using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(inputStream.AsStream(), XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                var entity = serializer.ReadObject(reader); //line A - here the problem 
                return entity as T;
            }                    
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work for the trivial case of `file = null`?

Comment: FYI, your workaround should be `var entity= await Task.Run<Entity>(() => GetASync<Entity>(file));` - you don't want to access `Result` in async code, because it handles errors differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have no idea why your code doesn't work. I'm suspecting a deadlock, but there *shouldn't* be one. :)

However, I do have a couple performance recommendations that would probably avoid the problem as a side effect. The first is to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)
                                           .StartAsTask()
                                           .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The other is to read the file into memory (asynchronously) and *then* parse it. (I'm assuming from your code that you're storing one object per file).

Comment: Thank you Stephen, the first recommendation did the trick, but I'm not sure why... For the second one, I don't understand the performance issue, can you explain?

Comment: `ReadObject` is synchronous. So, it will block a threadpool thread for the duration of the read (if you take out the `ConfigureAwait`, then it will block the UI thread instead). Also, the `IInputStream` wrapper implements synchronous reads as blocking on asynchronous reads - this means there's more objects allocated (e.g., `ManualResetEvent`). The best solution would be a `ReadObjectAsync`, but AFAIK that doesn't exist (yet), so an acceptable solution is to async read the file into memory, and then (synchronously) parse it. That way you don't have a threadpool thread blocked on I/O.

Comment: Regarding *why* it works: I suspect a deadlock in `ReadObject`, which was blocking the UI thread during the read. A deadlock would happen if the underlying async read attempted to complete on the UI thread (which it shouldn't be doing). I looked through the WinRT wrappers, but couldn't see where it would do that. The `ConfigureAwait` works by removing the UI context before the read operation starts - so the underlying async read will now complete on a threadpool thread. It does bug me, though, because it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed explanation, I still need to read more about async/await and programming for Windows 8 is a good way to dive into it.

Comment: Be sure to see Gragus' answer; he has confirmed it is a known bug. I expect it'll be fixed in a future Win8 build.

Answer (score 1):

Ping-back from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/3f192a81-073a-47ea-92e2-5ce02bf5ad33:

You are hitting a known issue in the .NET developer preview version that Microsoft distributed at the BUILD conference.
The issue is caused by some subtle specifics of the WinRT UI thread. As a result, any blocking WinRT stream-IO from managed code will lead to a deadlock, if performed from the UI thread. Asynchronous IO (e.g. `ReadAsync`) will work fine. The development team is aware of the problem and is working to fix it.

Please note, however, that even if and when the issue is fixed, performing blocking IO on the UI thread is not a good idea. Your application will block and be unresponsive for the duration of the operation. Some .NET APIs do not have async equivalents (yet) and even once they do, converting code may require work. If you have to perform a blocking IO operation, make sure to offload it to the thread pool:

```
DoUIStuff();
Int32 x = await Task.Run(() => {
    OpenStream();
    PerformBlockingIO();
    ProcessResults();
    return ComputeIOResults();
});
UseIOResults(x);
```

This way you keep your application responsive at all times. As a side effect, you will also work around the abovementioned bug and avoid the deadlock.